# If a 2-dimensional limit does not exist, can we argue that the limit is greater than some minimum?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

If we have a limit, for example,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{a x^2 + b y^2}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{equation}
then we can show that the limit "does not exist" if $a \neq b$ since taking the limit as $y \rightarrow 0$ first does not yield the same result as taking the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ first.

But if we let $c > \max[a,b]$, can we state that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{a x^2 + b y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \leq c
\end{equation}

If we take the limit along the direction $x=y$ for example, the limit approaches $\frac{a+b}{2} < c$.

If this does work, does it work in general?

Comment: How can you write down the limit in an inequality if it doesn't exist?

Comment: If you think about it in a 1-dimensional sense, if I have a function $y = 1$ if $x < 0$ and $y = 2$ if x > 0, then in general y > 0, is that correct?  Does this includes in the limit as x goes to 0?  That's what I'm asking in a multivariable case.

Comment: All the limit on two roads $A=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb R:\}$ y $B=\{(0,y):x\in\mathbb R:\}$, llegaras que en $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\in A}f(x,y)=a$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\in B}f(x,y)=b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem I see with
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{a x^2 + b y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \stackrel? \leq c
$$
is that for a sentence of this form to be meaningful,
the thing on the left side of "$\leq$" has to be a number.
The "$\leq$" symbol cannot "reach inside" the limit notation to make statements about the ways in which the limit fails.

And the limit on the left hand side **really does not exist** in any mathematical sense. You cannot even say the limit depends on which line you approach $(0,0)$ along, because the concept of
$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}$ does not say that you approach $(0,0)$ along a line -- you could go in along a spiral or on a path that zigzags.

But I think you could write
$$
\limsup_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{a x^2 + b y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = \max\{a,b\}.
$$

You can just write "$=$" here and not "$\leq$" because the "$\limsup$" notation already incorporates the "$\leq$" idea. In fact it seems to be what you were trying to write with "$\lim$" and "$\leq$".

You could also write
$$
\frac{a x^2 + b y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \leq \max\{a,b\} \quad \text{for} \quad
(x,y)\neq(0,0). 
$$

You don't need any kind of limit here because the statement starts out true and remains true no matter how you move $(x,y)$ around $(0,0)$.

Comment: I see; so it would be more of a notation issue that I'm struggling with.  Thanks for that

Comment: A thing about math is, if there's a useful idea that seems like it should be expressible in notation, someone has probably invented a notation to express it.

Comment: I'd add that sometimes we do have notation that "reaches inside" and changes the meanings of other symbols. E.g. usually "$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=c$" and "$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty$" are defined separately and not interpreted as literal equalities, and "$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ does not exist" is defined even though "$T$ does not exist" is nonsense for an arbitrary term $T$. Another example is "$f(x)=x^3+o(x)$". Students who expect notation to be strictly compositional can be confused when encountering things like this. (I feel like there's a better example that I'm forgetting.)